# Is $u \mapsto u'(0)$ continuous on $C^1([0,1])$ with the $C^0$-norm?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I need some help with this exercise:

> Is the functional $D$ defined by $u\mapsto u'(0)$ for $u\in C^1([0,1])$ linear and continuous?

First of all: $C^1([0,1])$ is the space of all functions $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is continuous and with continuous derivative. Since $[0,1]$ is compact, then we have that, for every $f\in C^1([0,1])$, $f(x),f'(x)$  are both bounded, i.e. $|f(x)|<M$, $|f'(x)|<N$ for $x\in[0,1]$.

I use on $C^1([0,1])$ the norm of $C^0([0,1])$ (I think that this exercise asks to use this norm): if $u\in C^1([0,1]) $, then $\|u\|_{C^0([0,1])}=\text{max}_{x\in[0,1]} |u(x)|$.

> The functional is clearly linear, is it continuous?

Since a linear functional is continuous iff it is bounded, one can show that $D$ is bounded.

In other words, I have to show that $\text{sup}_{u\in C^1([0,1])} \frac{|u'(0)|}{\|u\|}<\infty$. But now I don't know what to do. I wish I had a inequality like $|u'(0)|<C\|u\|$, with $C$ indipendent from $u$.

Comment: Are you sure you are not meant to consider the typical $C^1$ norm, $\|f\|=\|f\|_\infty+\|f'\|_\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $D(\sin(nx)) = n$ for any $n$.

Comment: So it is not a bounded functional. Right?